# Hide one dropdown in side menu when another opens

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, drop-down-menu

I'm a total newbie in Javascript, so really need your help, guys.

I have a vertical submenu, and I'd like to hide one dropdown item as soon as another one is opened. I've been browsing what feels like for ages today, and I assume I have to use the 'toggle' method somehow, maybe even an onclick function, but so far, I haven't been able to figure out how, and mainly, how to make it work with an already existing Javascript piece of code. The answer must be very simple, and yet... Would be awesome if you could help me.

**My code:**

HTML (just deleted a few `<a></a>` lines to save some space):

```
<div class="sidenav">
  <button class="dropdown-btn">Cloud & Datacenter Infrastruktur 
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down fa-border"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-container">
  <div class="subpoints">
    <a href="#company">AWS Infrastruktur</a>
    <a href="#team">MS Azure</a>
    <a href="#careers">Google Cloud</a>
</div>
  </div>
  <button class="dropdown-btn">BI / Analytics 
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down fa-border"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-container">
    <div class="subpoints">
    <a href="#company">BI & Datawarehouse</a>
    <a href="#team">Operational Analytics</a>
    <a href="#careers">Data Science</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="dropdown-btn">IT Security 
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down fa-border"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-container">
    <div class="subpoints">
    <a href="#bring">IT-Security Architektur / IT Security Compliance</a>
    <a href="#deliver">IT-Security Analyse + Pentesting</a>
    <a href="#package">IT-Security Operations</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS (in case it's relevant):

```
/* Sidenav, full height */
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 15em;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

/* Style the sidenav links and the dropdown button */
.sidenav a, .dropdown-btn {
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  font-family:Roboto;
  font-weight:300;
  line-height:1.5em;
}

/* On mouse-over */
.sidenav a:hover, .dropdown-btn:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: underline #fcaf17;
  text-underline-offset: 0.3em;
}

/* Add an active class to the active dropdown button */
.active {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: underline #fcaf17;
  text-underline-offset: 0.3em;
}

/* Dropdown container (hidden by default). Optional: add a lighter background color and some left padding to change the design of the dropdown content */
.dropdown-container {
  display: none;
  color:#717375;
}
.subpoints {
  padding-left: 2.8em;
}

.dropdown-container a {
  background-color: #fff;
  color:#717375;
  padding-left: 3em;
}

.dropdown-container a:hover {
  color:#717375;
  background-color:#fcaf17;
  display: block;
}

/* Optional: Style the caret down icon */
.fa-caret-down {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 0.8em;
}

.fa-border {
  border-style:none;
}
```

And here's one piece of Javascript that I already have in place in order to shift all lower elements down when a dropdown is opened (courtesy of W3Schools).

```
var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
  dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.classList.toggle("active");
  var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
  if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block") {
  dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
  } else {
  dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
  }
  });
}
```

Now I need an additional piece of Javascript to make the previous dropdown close when the next one is opened... Here is how it's going to be implemented on a website, right in the header area: [Link](http://mvise3.staging.wpengine.com/mvise-ag-startseite-version2/)

Thanks a lot for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through all the dropdown containers and style them with `display:none` before you add `display:block` to the clicked element like this:

```js
var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");
//grab all the dropdowncontainers to apply display none to
var dropdowncontainers = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-container');
var i;

for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
  dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
  var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
  if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block") {
  dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
  //remove active class when clicked on active element
  this.classList.remove("active");
  } else {
  //loop through all containers
  for (var i = 0; i < dropdowncontainers.length; i++) {
    //add the style.display to all elements
    dropdowncontainers[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
  //loop through all buttons
  for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
  //remove class active from all buttons
    dropdown[i].classList.remove("active");
  }
  //add class active to clicked button
  this.classList.add("active");
  //add display block to the right dropdown container
  dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
  }
  });
}
```

```css
/* Sidenav, full height */
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 15em;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

/* Style the sidenav links and the dropdown button */
.sidenav a, .dropdown-btn {
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  font-family:Roboto;
  font-weight:300;
  line-height:1.5em;
}

/* On mouse-over */
.sidenav a:hover, .dropdown-btn:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: underline #fcaf17;
  text-underline-offset: 0.3em;
}

/* Add an active class to the active dropdown button */
.active {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: underline #fcaf17;
  text-underline-offset: 0.3em;
}

/* Dropdown container (hidden by default). Optional: add a lighter background color and some left padding to change the design of the dropdown content */
.dropdown-container {
  display: none;
  color:#717375;
}
.subpoints {
  padding-left: 2.8em;
}

.dropdown-container a {
  background-color: #fff;
  color:#717375;
  padding-left: 3em;
}

.dropdown-container a:hover {
  color:#717375;
  background-color:#fcaf17;
  display: block;
}

/* Optional: Style the caret down icon */
.fa-caret-down {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 0.8em;
}

.fa-border {
  border-style:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidenav">
  <button class="dropdown-btn">Cloud & Datacenter Infrastruktur 
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down fa-border"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-container">
  <div class="subpoints">
    <a href="#company">AWS Infrastruktur</a>
    <a href="#team">MS Azure</a>
    <a href="#careers">Google Cloud</a>
</div>
  </div>
  <button class="dropdown-btn">BI / Analytics 
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down fa-border"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-container">
    <div class="subpoints">
    <a href="#company">BI & Datawarehouse</a>
    <a href="#team">Operational Analytics</a>
    <a href="#careers">Data Science</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="dropdown-btn">IT Security 
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down fa-border"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-container">
    <div class="subpoints">
    <a href="#bring">IT-Security Architektur / IT Security Compliance</a>
    <a href="#deliver">IT-Security Analyse + Pentesting</a>
    <a href="#package">IT-Security Operations</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> EDIT: added code to prevent active class on multiple `dropdown-btn` elements

Comment: Omg, it works!!! Gosh, really, I spent about 3 hours if not more trying to figure out the solution and you just solved it in a few minutes – I bow in front of you, Ramon. I would have upvoted your answer, but apparently, I don't have enough credits yet to cast a vote – so instead, a HUGE thank you!!! Your answer really made my day!

Comment: No problem, one small thing i noticed, the `this.classList.toggle("active");` is why the buttons get the underline i suppose, but since you can close the other still opened tab by clicking a new one, you can have all 3 underlined at all times. to fix that you could look for any `.dropdown-btn` having class `active` and removing that before adding class `active` to the current opened item

Comment: i've edited my solution so it prevents multiple buttons having the active class at the same time

Comment: Oh yes, I didn't even notice those yellow underlines due to the sheer excitement:D I've just implemented your edited solution – and it works perfectly now:) I can't thank you enough for your help, this is awesome!